# How do I check the server location on Nord VPN?

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn

I have just installed Ubuntu and installed Nord VPN. It didn’t really give me an option for which country I’ve connected to and I’m unable to check which one it is.

How do I check which server I'm on and how do I change them if needed? I’m running Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: are you using openvpn to connect? Are you connecting via the command line? The network manager? Have you tried googling around? NordVPN has a pretty good guide on setting up the vpn service and selecting which server you want https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection status with `nordvpn status` and note the `country` and `city`. You can use `nordvpn countries` to see the list of countries where servers are available, then you can pick a country and look at the cities (optional) with `nordvpn cities United_States` and connect with  `nordvpn connect United_States Atlanta` for city level or just `nordvpn connect United_States`.